# How to restrict a Stream to run sequentially, and prevent it from running in parallel?

Tags: java, java-stream, spliterator

I have a method that returns a stream that is generated from a custom spliterator; the spliterator is not tread safe. Since the spliterator is not tread safe, and it maintains state, I want to prevent it from running in parallel. Is there a way to **prevent** the returned stream from running in parallel?

I have not been able to find any documentation or examples that do this. I did find a `sequential()` method on the `BaseStream` class, but that does not appear to prevent a user from then calling `parallel()` to get a parallel stream.

Comment: You don't need a spliterator to be thread safe to be usable for parallel usage.  The stream framework will take care of managing thread safety for you.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. The documentation explicitely says: *Despite their obvious utility in parallel algorithms, spliterators are not expected to be thread-safe*.

Comment: @JBNizet The full sentence you quoted is "*Despite their obvious utility in parallel algorithms, spliterators are not expected to be thread-safe; instead, implementations of parallel algorithms using spliterators should ensure that the spliterator is only used by one thread at a time.*". It is the second half of that sentence that concerns me, I was not able to find any documentation that states that parallel streams will access the spliterator sequentially.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Is there any documentation that states that the stream framework will operate correctly on a non-thread safe spliterator?

Comment: @MikeRylander that documentation is for people writing their own stream like utilities; you can safely assume the stream library itself is correctly implemented. You can safely assume the JDK follows its own advice.  Additionally, none of the JDKs built in spliterators are thread safe, which would kind of defeat the point of parallel streams if that broke things.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, spliterators may not care about thread-safety if the peers created by splitting procedure do not mutate the shared state. This is not always true. [Here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/file/57d0a62b4754/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/stream/WhileOps.java#l652)'s example of Spliterator in JDK-9 which maintains shared state (`AtomicBoolean` variable). Sometimes I write much more sophisticated spliterators which should care much about thread-safety.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parallel stream calls `trySplit()` method of your spliterator to split your task to the several parts. It's [absolutely legit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html#trySplit--) to return `null` from `trySplit()` saying that "I refuse to split". In this case the stream created from your spliterator will be executed sequentially even if `.parallel()` was explicitly called.

However in general you may provide at least a limited parallelism extending the [`AbstractSpliterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator.html) class. It provides default `trySplit()` implementation which reads some input elements calling your `tryAdvance()` method, storing them into array and returning the spliterator on that array, so this part can be processed separately and totally independent on your spliterator. This is "poor man" parallelization, but still may improve the speed if the downstream pipeline operations are time consuming.

Finally note that in most simple cases Spliterator implementation should not be thread safe. If you provide your own efficient `trySplit()` implementation, it's guaranteed that the original spliterator and the newly created spliterator will be processed in totally independent manner. So if you don't modify the shared state in prefix and suffix spliterator after splitting, you should not care about thread-safety.

Comment: Thanks, having `trySplit()` return null does appear to prevent parallel execution. Do you know of any documentation for streams that states it will use `trySplit()` to implement parallelism?

Comment: @MikeRylander, The [Spliterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html) class doc says: "A Spliterator may also partition off some of its elements (using trySplit()) as another Spliterator, to be used in possibly-parallel operations. Operations using a Spliterator that cannot split, or does so in a highly imbalanced or inefficient manner, are unlikely to benefit from parallelism."

Answer (score 0):

Streams are synchronous by default, so the question is kinda irrelevant if you document your library correctly. It's the user's responsibility to make sure the library they are using is Thread-Safe. Just make obvious yours is not.

There is a way to check the Thread if you can send the Thread ID on the server side and receive it on the client side through an API:

```
Thread.currentThread().getId()
```

And compare it with your Thread ID when you receive it. Throw an `Exception` with a clear error message "Not Thread-Safe!" when they are different.