# how to force Java 8 streams to execute sequentially?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a Stream as a method's argument. I don't know if it parallel or not.
How can I guarantee sequential execute it?

(no if/else/instance of pls)

Thanks

Comment: You can simply use `sequential()`.

Comment: @nullpointer throw me the link in comments here (I'll take a look), I can still vote to close...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33835683/how-to-restrict-a-stream-to-run-sequentially-and-prevent-it-from-running-in-par ;  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29216588/how-to-ensure-order-of-processing-in-java8-streams ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742640/calling-sequential-on-parallel-stream-makes-all-previous-operations-sequential @Eugene

Answer (score 9, accepted):

wait... just invoke `sequential()` on it?

This is just a flag so the last invocation of `sequential/parallel` wins, that means even if your stream is `parallel` and you receive it as a method argument, just invoke `sequential` anywhere before the terminal operation and you are done

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35744490/1746118) is worth a read as well.